# jquery .get() displays nothing in internet explorer

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code but it does not seem to want to work in ie, does anybody know why? I have seen solutions with setting cache to false, is this correct? If so how would i implement into my code?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - not cross domain (sorry)

```
<script>
    $.get("staffnotices/index.php", function(data) {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
    $("#bbs").html(data);
    });
</script>
<div id="bbs">
</div>
```

Comment: is it content from the same server? Otherwise it is maybe a cross-site issue!
Read: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/169672-internet-explorer-cross-site-scripting-xss-filter-turn-off.html

Comment: Like @Florian Bauer said: _'Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.'_

Comment: What is the precise problem you are having? Does the callback ever get called? (you can check with an alert if you don't have developer tools on your IE)

Comment: i have put alert("I am an alert box!"); after $("#bbs").html(data); the alert works in ie but not in opera. the .get works in opera but not ie

Answer (score 1):

Set your browser mode to IE7 OR IE8 OR IE9 and check the result. This issue is in compatibility mode.

Comment: @Codded can you please use alert(data) instead of alerting other string. Can you see proper response in alert box?

Comment: Ok done this, it alerts the content that should be there. but the .get() is not displaying it in the div.

Comment: It means that this is not cache issue.

Comment: @Codded what is your IE version on which this issue is encountering?

Comment: @Codded please press f12 and change browser mode to IE9 and then try. I hope this will be set with compatibility mode right now.

Comment: have done this, i changed to all the options but still nothing on any

Comment: ahh browser mode and document mode set to ie9 have now displayed the data in the div. How do i fix this though for others?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `cache` option to `false` would be the first thing to try. You can do that by adding this before your call to `$.get()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

You only need to do that once per page, since it sets the global AJAX options and will affect all AJAX requests (unless they explicitly set the option to a different value).

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
    $.get("staffnotices/index.php", function(data) {
        $("#bbs").html(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i have added this, please see edited question, but still nothing

Comment: @Codded You need to call it *before* making the AJAX request, you currently have it in the callback function (which is executed *after* the AJAX request has returned). I've edited my answer to demonstrate where it should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get("staffnotices/index.php", function(data) {
    $("#bbs").html(data);
  });
});
```